# Same drupal webform is showing error messages in two different way, on different palces in the same website

Tags: webforms

I am using drupal webform for my website, I am using single Contact Us form on multiple places in my website.

But the problem is on different places the way of showing error message is different, its not uniform through out the website.

[image: My webform which I am using everywhere]

Here is the image that shows the first way that how error messages comes-
[image: First way how error message display]

and here is the image that shows the second way to show error messages-
[image: Second way how error display]

I want first type of error messages which is in red box.

Please help me that how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: The first version is _server-side_ validation; the second version is _client-side_ validation. Trust me, you want both

Comment: So if I am not specifying anywhere that whether to use client side validation or server side validation then on behalf of what it is deciding?

Comment: Client-side validation is driven by attributes on form elements, so it's likely you have a module or theme installed which is adding the HTML5 `required` attribute, for example. You'll probably also have `<input type="email">` for email fields, which will require a valid email before form submission, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module. I hope through this you can solve your issue.

> This module adds an extra tab to each webform node, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your webform components. You can create
>   one or more of the predefined validation rules, and select which
>   webform component(s) should be validated against those. By using the
>   hooks provided by this module, you can also define your own validation
>   rules in your own modules.